# Conditionally Color MKCircle on Map in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I need to display a map of circles and polygons, and each circle or polygon may be different colors.

My initial plan was to subclass MKCircle and MKPolygon and add an instance variable for my Region class (which has information that will determine the color of the shape on the map) but that is not possible to subclass either of those

Any ideas?

Here is what I have so far:

```
// draw the regions
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKCircle {
        // display circles on the map
        let circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)


        circle.strokeColor = UIColor.red // THIS SHOULD BE CONDITIONAL (sometimes red, sometimes green -> depends on a class that I have called region)
        circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
        circle.lineWidth = 1
        return circle
    } else if overlay is MKPolygon {
        // display polygons on the map
        let poly = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        poly.strokeColor = UIColor.red // THIS SHOULD BE CONDITIONAL (sometimes red, sometimes green -> depends on a class that I have called region)
        poly.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
        poly.lineWidth = 1
        return poly
    } else {
        return MKPolylineRenderer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old thread, but I thought I'll share how I did this

I used stored properties of extensions to create a variable which could differentiate between if the MKCircle was for a member or a place as I required it

Here is the sample code:

```
extension MKCircle {
    
    enum type {
        case place
        case member
    }
    
    private static var savedCircleType: type = .member
    
    var circleType : type {
        get{
            return MKCircle.savedCircleType
        }
        set(newValue) {
            MKCircle.savedCircleType = newValue
        }
    }
    
}
```

When adding annotation, do this

```
let circle = MKCircle(center: currentLocationPin.coordinate, radius: 200)
circle.circleType = .member // or .place in my case
self.mapView.addOverlay(circle)
self.mapView.addAnnotation(currentLocationPin)
```

And finally in the MKMapView delegate

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKCircle {
            let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            let color: UIColor = (circleRenderer.circle.circleType == .place) ? .themeGreen : .red
            circleRenderer.strokeColor = color
            circleRenderer.fillColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
            circleRenderer.lineWidth = 2.0
            return circleRenderer
        } else {
            return MKPolylineRenderer()
        }
    }
```

Result :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApH9I.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You say you can't subclass MKCircle or MKPolygon, so you have no way to pass extra info associated with this overlay into the delegate method in the `overlay` parameter.

But what you *can* do is write your own NSObject subclass that conforms to the MKOverlay protocol. Now you can add any instance property you like. For simplicity, your MKOverlay adopter can itself wrap an MKCircle or MKPolygon but there is no actual need for this.

Comment: It seems like there should be an easier/more elegant solution to this lol

Comment: I don’t see how it’s not easy and elegant. I do this all the time. Plus you can subclass the renderer. So your delegate method can be a lot simpler.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? Compared to the Google Maps Android SDK and the Google Maps JavaScript API this is way overcomplicated when all I want to do is if (something) color is red else color is green lol. This is my first time using MapKit.

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch21p744maps/ch34p1008maps/ViewController.swift - set `which` to `10` to see the example where I supply my own path overlay and my own path overlay renderer. Note how simple that makes the delegate method.